# Prevent express.js from sending all angular client code before login

Tags: angular, express, authentication, mean

I use Mean.io for a website and I don't want users to have all my angular client code without prior login. Right now, everybody with my website URL can see all my angular code and I want to prevent that from happening. How to configure express?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Prepare another page as a Login page and serve that as default. Once the user is authenticated, serve your actual page with the Angular application.

You may check if the user is not authenticated, then redirect to the `/login` page. once the user is authenticated, you may redirect the user to your base URL `/` and serve the actual application.

You must be checking whether the user is authenticated using a middleware.

```
app.use(function (req, res, next) {  
    // redirect if not authenticated
    res.redirect('/login'); 

    // else use next()
    next() 
})

app.get('/login', function (req, res) { })

app.get('/', function (req, res) {  })
```

**PS: this is just a brief idea of what can be done. You need to verify whether it is working correctly.**